# Is there any way to integer sort in hbase?

Tags: hbase

As far as I know , HBase supports only the bytes array for write purpose.

Is there any way to receive the scanned results in *integer sort order* and not as *lexicographical order*

for example

```
1

2

10
```

not as

```
1

10

2
```

some people said we can store like

```
00001

00002

00010
```

Is there any alternative way?

Comment: Saying that hbase sorts keys lexicographical is only half true - keys are merely byte arrays and are sorted as byte arrays. Use `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes` to convert your keys to bytes (and vice versa), and while youre there take a look at `ByteArrayComparator`

Comment: So you are saying i will not get lexicographical sorted order every time i fetch the data, right?

Comment: If you use Bytes utility class to save your integer keys as byte arrays, they will be sorted by their integer value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes:

```
  /**
   * Convert an int value to a byte array.  Big-endian.  Same as what DataOutputStream.writeInt
   * does.
   *
   * @param val value
   * @return the byte array
   */
  public static byte[] toBytes(int val) {
    byte [] b = new byte[4];
    for(int i = 3; i > 0; i--) {
      b[i] = (byte) val;
      val >>>= 8;
    }
    b[0] = (byte) val;
    return b;
  }
```

So you can clearly see that you can use this utility class to convert your keys just before you save them. When fetched, they will be sorted by their integer value.
Effectively this handle the padding you mentioned in your comment.